# Calendar array to return unique results based on date and PO number

Tags: arrays, indexing, calendar, match

I am trying to modify the below array to determine if a date and PO number have already been returned as a result for a date then skip to the next PO. see the attached screen capture which is returning the same PO number multiple times in the calendar.

I'm using named ranges (CalList, PO_Number) when referencing the table holding all the data.

=IFERROR(INDEX(CalList,SMALL(IF(Date=A$8,ROW(Date)),ROW(1:1))-TableRowStart,5),"")

In the screen capture "Garb" is showing up 3 times and "Stance" 5 times, and I'm looking for the array formula to determine that PO and Date has already been used in the calendar so skip to the next matching date and PO.
[Screen Capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2CsV.jpg)

Comment: I'm getting an error message but this formula seems closer to what I am trying to accomplish

=IFERROR(INDEX(CalList,SMALL(IF(Date=A$8,IF(MATCH(A$9:A$18&A$8, Date&A$8,0)=ROW(Date),ROW(1:1)))-TableRowStart,5),""))

Comment: problem solved on another site:
http://www.excelguru.ca/forums/showthread.php?6822-Calendar-array-to-return-unique-results-based-on-date-and-PO-number&p=27981#post27981